# Deleting first row in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying with no success to create a new datatable (from another datatable) in another function

```
Session["Tissues"] = tableword;// I dont load them again
Session["Randomtable"] = tableword;
```

and basically what I need is to Delete the first row of the dataTable in one table with the code behind.

```
private void Question_table()
{
    if (Session["Tissues"] != null)
    {           
        DataTable table_word =  (DataTable)Session["Tissues"];
        DataTable table_random = (DataTable)Session["Randomtable"];        
        GridView3.DataSource = table_random;
        GridView3.DataBind();

             string q_name = "";
            DataRow row = table_word.Rows[0];
            if (row["name"] != null) // This will check the null values also (if you want to check).
            {
                // Do whatever you want.
                q_name = row["name"].ToString();

            }
            if (row["image"] != null) // This will check the null values also (if you want to check).
            {
                q_image = row["image"].ToString();
            }
            Next_Question(q_name, q_image, table_random);
            Label3.Text = q_name;
            Label4.Text = q_image;
            row.Delete();
            // table_word.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
           // table_word.Rows.Remove(row);
          //  table_word.Rows.Remove(table_word.Rows[0]); 
           Session["Tissues"] = table_word;

    }
}
```

and I call

```
Question_table();
```

after click an image button.

The problem is when i try delete only one row of one datatable but it deletes the contents of both datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `datatable` is `reference type` and with following statement, this means both points to single memory i.e. address of tableword.

```
Session["Tissues"] = tableword;// I dont load them again
Session["Randomtable"] = tableword;
```

So when you retrieve from session and delete one row, it will delete that from 2nd and 2nd points to same datable.